# 2 time formats in excel issue with date

Tags: excel

I have an excel data with 5000 rows. I need to filter on data however as the data has been pulled from Oracle database it has been captured with date and time stamp. Now I need to filter the data on only time basis as date is the same i.e. 31st March. So there are 2 issues:-
1) How should I filter the data only basis time.
2) the other issue is the time has been captured in 2 ways- 9:01 pm & 21:01 pm. Can you please advice on to combined these 2 time frame formats into 1 and apply filter. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the date and time are in a string format, use the DateValue and TimeValue formulas to construct the serial date version.

you can construct your own date using as search critera

```
=Date(Year,Month,Day)  (e.g. today = 42,096.00)
```

then add the desired time by using

```
=TimeValue("14:30")   (0.604166667)
```

Add the two together to get half of your conditional criteria.

```
=Date(Year,Month,Day) + TimeValue("14:30")
```

You will also need to convert the time strings from Oracle into serial version also using the same formulas.